# Mailer Displays gaps on left and right of the images

Tags: html, css

I am developing a mailer so on my outlook it looks fine but on my Gmail it shows Spacing on the left and right of the image. I used `style="display:block"` which only removed the spacing at the bottom. How do I remove on the left and on the right?

Here is my code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="695px">
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><a href="/index.html" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#677880; text-decoration:none"><span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#677880;">View on the web</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height="10px"><img src="/images/spacer.gif"  height="10" width="1" style="display:block;" border="0" alt="Spacer"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" border="0" align="right"><img src="/images/top.jpg" width="695" height="52" border="0" style="display:block;" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="695px">
              <tr>
                <td width="461px" border="0" valign="top" align="right"><img src="/images/father-and-husband.jpg" width="461" height="300" style="display:block;" border="0" ></td>
                <td valign="top" width="234px" border="0"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="234px">
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" border="0"><a href="#" style="border:0"><img src="/images/life-2-lefe-logo.jpg" width="234" height="131" style="display:block" border="0" alt="Click here to visit our website" title="Click here to visit our website" align="left"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td valign="top" border="0"><img src="/images/botton-logo.jpg" width="234" height="169" style="display:block" border="0" align="left"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="695px">
              <tr>
                <td border="0" valign="top" align="right"><a href="#" style="border:0"><img src="/images/donating-a-kidney.jpg" width="461" height="290" style="display:block;margin:0" border="0" alt="Click here to email us" title="Click here to email us"></a></td>
                <td border="0" valign="top"><img src="/images/right-email.jpg" width="234" height="290" style="display:block" border="0" align="left"></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td border="0" valign="top" align="right"><img src="/images/bottom.jpg" width="695" height="341" style="display:block" border="0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="center" height="30" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#677880;">If you do not wish to recieve any further email notifications, <a style="color:#ec1c23;" href="{{components.unsubscribe}}" target="_blank">click here to unsubscribe.</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Which of the images are you complaining about exactly?There are several. It would help if you would turn this into a snippet demonstrating the issue, with actual working imgs.

Comment: If you take a look on the below image, you will find that the is a vertical white line on the mailer. That line should not be there.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks, [enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xmTKW.jpg)

Comment: That doesn't help pinpoint the problem. It's still not clear which image is the culprit. Please post a complete example that demonstrates the issue.